# Looking for a Good Practice of Array List Declaration of different types of user inputs in C#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, algorithm, complexity-theory

I need help im trying to shorten a long code by this algorithm.

I use this on my TextBox Fields

```
Textbox[] Fields = new Textbox[] { txtbox1, txtbox2, txtbox3.. };
string[] arr = { stringVariable1, stringVariable2, stringVariable3.. };

int cnt = 0;
foreach(var r in Fields.AsEnumerable())
{
    r.Text = arr[cnt].toString();
    cnt++;
}
```

So when the form loads the user input fields will be populated based on the variable if it's empty or have value.

But how if i have different Type of Fields? like datepicker value, combobox and textbox, radiobutton and checkbox fields.

```
object[] fields = new object[] { datepicker1, Txtbox1, ComboBox1, CheckBox1 };
```

The Match it with an Array i declared with different type of Objects too

```
object[] arr = { DateVar1, TxtBoxVarString1, ComboBoxstring1, CboxBool1, int.. }
```

is it possible to make declare things like this so i can shorten my code or do i have to do it manually because it's not possible.

I have tried this code:

```
ArrayList arrvar = new ArrayList(); object[] obj = new object[] { datevarvalue1, cboxvarbool1, rbtnvarbool1, stringvar1.. etc.. etc.. }

arrvar.addrange(obj); try { List Fields = new List { AddinfoDOB.Value, CheckBox1.Checked, RadioButton1.Checked, AddinfoPlaceOfBirth.Text, AddInfoCmbBoxBloodT.Text, AddInfoCmbBoxOrigin.Text, AddInfoCmbBoxCitizenship.Text, AddInfoCmbBoxLanguage.Text, AddInfoAddress01.Text };

                int cnt = 0;
                foreach (object r in Fields.AsEnumerable())
                {
                    Fields[cnt] = arrvar[cnt];
                    cnt++;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString()); }
```

Error Message: "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."

Comment: All controls than should have `.Text` property. If they not - then it is not possible. Is this ASP.NET controls or Winforms or WPF or something else?

Comment: windows form sir and also in asp.net what should be the possible way i could shorten my code and not doing a repeat call for the certain fields to populate using arrays

Comment: It's not really clear what your problem is. The exception you describe is because you are assigning a new value to `Fields[cnt]` while you are enumerating the elements of `Fields`. See marked duplicates for answers to that. As for the rest, `object[]` works fine as you've shown it, so I don't know why you think you need something else.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, OP's question was about how "dynamically" update controls with correspondent values. Provided exception is just "side-effect" of one of the approaches OP tried. _As for the rest, object[] works fine as you've shown it_ - it will not work. Main question is how update multiple different controls with correspondent values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can declare that kind of array. I just tested it and it works. Try this as an example:

Add a button and a checkbox.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

string temp = "Hi!";

Object[] arr = new Object[] { button1, checkBox1, temp };

foreach(Object a in arr)
{
    if (a is button)
        MessageBox.Show(((Button)a).Name);
    else if (a is CheckBox)
        MessageBox.Show(((CheckBox)a).Name);
    else if (a is String)
        MessageBox.Show(((String)a));
}
```

Comment: yes but how do i insert my variable value to that object in the foreach array when the option is only .ToString and no .Text or .Value or .Checked

Comment: Use for example ((Button)a).Text="test"; //where Button is the type of object, a is the variable name. The parenthesis are needed.

Comment: Sir Thank you for the Solution Method

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by introducing collection of "update" functions
Create collection of update functions and correspondent collection of values

```
var updateFunctions = new List<Action<object>>
{
    value => textbox.Text = (string)value,
    value => datepicker.Value = (DateTime)value,
    value => checkbox.Checked = (bool)value,
};

var values = new List<object>
{
    "TextBox value",
    DateTime.Now,
    true,
};

for(var index = 0; i < updateFunctions.Count; i++)
{
    var update = updateFunctions[i];
    var value = values[i];
    update(value);
}
```

But for me this approach seems little-bid like "hack-workaround", because you need to check that both collections `values` and `control updates` should be in "sync".
Same can be achieved with data-binding on little bid cleaner way

Create a class for values you want display in controls

```
public class DisplayData
{
    public string Name {get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthdate {get; set; }
    public bool IsActive {get; set; }
}
```

Then in form constructor "bind" controls to the data

```
public YourForm() // Form constructor
{
    InitializeComponents();

    var data = new DisplayData
    {
        Name = "name",
        Birthdate = DateTime.Now,
        IsActive = true
    };

    textbox.DataBindings.Add("Text", data, "Name");
    dateTimePicker.DataBindings.Add("Value", data, "Birthdate");
    checkBox.DataBindings.Add("Checked", data, "IsActive");
}
```

When you change control value, correspondent value in the `data` instance will be changed as well.

If you made `DisplayData` class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and will raise `PropertyChanged` event every time you change value in `data` instance - control will be updated automatically.

Comment: i'm assuming this is on asp.net but can this method be also done in windows application form?

Comment: Both approaches are for windows application form controls.

Comment: Sir Ty for the Replied Answer i will also study and use this method.